# Detect when other Application is launched in React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want my react native app to detect when Google Maps app is open to show some travel tip. Is it possible?

Comment: From your app or just in general?

Comment: In general if my app is running in background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not detect if another app is launched for security reasons. Installed apps can´t listen another apps because they are "sandboxed".

You can only interact with another apps opening it throught your app by Deeplinking or detecting if is or not installed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a limitation of React Native. All iOS applications cannot access other applications, except to open it or share some resources.