# Can i check background running apps react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing a app in react native. While the app start any financial transaction it should scan if other application are running in the background or not both in iOS and Android platform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect when other Application is launched in React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431455/detect-when-other-application-is-launched-in-react-native-app)

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a year, but:
[Detect when other Application is launched in React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431455/detect-when-other-application-is-launched-in-react-native-app/52856128)

Due to security concerns, apps are "sandboxed". You can't tell what other apps are running on the device.

You can however see what apps are INSTALLED on the device, and you can do things like deep-linking to open other apps on the device.